# for each gives different result?

Tags: python

I tried to add the comma seprated value between the `:` seprated then multiply the whole value
For example, consider my value is `1,2,3:4,5,6`
I want to add the 1+2+3 ,and 4+5+6 then multiply the result of this value so answer is 6 * 15 = 90

For my bellow data i want the result is `7.224` but this script gives  `61.658886435`
I don't know what is the problem in  my script'

```
ar = "0.212,1.231,0.112:1.001,3.212,0.002:0.002,0.0001,1.1"
x_data = ar.split(":")
x_final = 1
x_add = 0
for i in x_data:
    x_each = i.split(",")
    for j in x_each:
        x_add = x_add + float(j)
    x_final = x_add * x_final

print x_final
```

Is any possible way to get the result without iterating loop? For above problem

Comment: Use missed the initialize value in side looping.

Comment: I'm confused by your example. You said you wanted to multiply the results but then added them. Dd you mean 6*15=90?

Comment: @Turn Thanks for your comment. Post edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use missed the initialize value as zero (x_add = 0) in each iterating. So your script add with the previous values

```
ar = "0.212,1.231,0.112:1.001,3.212,0.002:0.002,0.0001,1.1"
x_data = ar.split(":")
x_final = 1
for i in x_data:
    x_each = i.split(",")
    x_add = 0             # Here you not initialize it
    for j in x_each:
        x_add = x_add + float(j)
    x_final = x_add * x_final

print x_final
```

> !!! As from @jpmc26 and @soon comment. Avoid using eval, and conform your input string format. 
>   Without looping use regex for to do it

Use regex for solve your problem without looping.

```
ar = "0.212,1.231,0.112:1.001,3.212,0.002:0.002,0.0001,1.1"
import re
ar = "("+ar                      #Add the ( with your data 
ar = re.sub(r",","+",ar)         #Substitute with + instead of ,
ar = re.sub(r"(?=\:|$)",")",ar)  #look ahead for add `)` after colon
ar = re.sub(r"(?<=)\:","*(",ar)  #Replace the color with *

#NOw you data look likes(0.212+1.231+0.112)*(1.001+3.212+0.002)*(0.002+0.0001+1.1)
#Finally evaluvate the string as a expression
print eval(ar)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `eval` here for safety reasons

Comment: @soon why? What is reason?

Comment: It evaluates given string as Python code. Just try `ar = "__import__('os.path').getcwd()"`

Comment: @soon ohh yes .I got it. But user input look likes comma and colon separated so i recommended for, use regex and eval for a problem.  But i clearly understood what you trying to saying afterwards i try to avoid eval in my script.  Thank you for you sharing.

Comment: Because this is likely to be input from some external source. Why in the heck would you ever trust an arbitrary string from an external source for `eval`? That's just asking for trouble. **Don't do it.** (`eval` is pretty much *never* necessary and *always* frowned upon.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Thank you for your usefull comment. user was accepted my answer. So i couldn't remove my post. But i edited the post with warning. And then can you share the drawback of the eval because most of my application development i am using eval.

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be also solved in a functional way:

1. You have to multiply all values in the list - this is what `functools.reduce` + `operator.mul` for
2. You have to sum up all values in all inner lists - this is what `sum` for

Example:

```
In [5]: ar = "0.212,1.231,0.112:1.001,3.212,0.002:0.002,0.0001,1.1"

In [6]: import operator

In [7]: import functools

In [8]: functools.reduce(operator.mul, (sum(float(x) for x in s.split(',')) for s in ar.split(':')))
Out[8]: 7.223521582500001
```

Comment: What's the difference between functools.reduce and just plain vanilla reduce?

Comment: @Untitled123, there is no difference, but "*plain valilla `reduce`*" does not exist in Python 3 anymore, only as `functools` member

Answer (score 1):

I don't necessarily recommend this complicated expression, but you can do it with list comprehensions and avoid the for loops:

```
import operator

ar = "0.212,1.231,0.112:1.001,3.212,0.002:0.002,0.0001,1.1"
reduce(operator.mul, [sum([float(n) for n in e]) for e in [x.split(',') for x in ar.split(":")]], 1)
```

Comment: There is no reason for list comprehensions, you may just use generator expressions (take look at the example in my post)

Comment: Not to mention that your code is generally more concise than mine.